# Cloning a Dropdown list using Jquery and appending to a Dynamic Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I Have a Dropdownlist with id ="mainDDL" already have in my page with some Data..

Now I want to clone this Dropdownlist and append to a Div.

I am using the following code:

```
 var ddl = $("#mainDDL").clone();                                                             
 ddl.attr("id", "ddlCloned");
 ddl.attr("name", "ddlCloned"); 
 var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
 innerDiv.innerHTML=ddl[0];
```

But when i am checking the "innerDiv" in Console window..It shows :

> [object HTMLDivElement]

Can any one please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for .append?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ddl = $("#mainDDL").clone();
  ddl.attr("id", "ddlCloned");
  ddl.attr("name", "ddlCloned");
  var innerDiv = $("<div />").appendTo('body');
  innerDiv.append(ddl);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ojex7f5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **jQuery** instead pure **JavaScript** ?

```
 var ddl = $("#mainDDL").clone();                                                             
 ddl.attr("id", "ddlCloned");
 ddl.attr("name", "ddlCloned"); 
 var innerDiv = $('div');
 innerDiv.append(ddl[0]);
```

The problem is that the **innerHTML** expects a **string** value not a DOM Element (object) so when you assign `ddl[0]`, the **toString()** function of the object is called and appended the result to your `div`.

If you want to resolve it using **JavaScript** you need to call `appendChild()` function.

```
 var ddl = $("#mainDDL").clone();   
 ddl.attr("id", "ddlCloned");
 ddl.attr("name", "ddlCloned"); 
 var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
 innerDiv.appendChild(ddl[0]);
```

*Note that you have a mix of jQuery and JavaScript for handle de DOM, I recommend just pick one to have a more readable code.